# API requires access token - so how do I create a new user account

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, security

I'm not sure of the best practice or how to get around this. I have an API which requires an access token. This token is provided via oauth when a user logs in. How do I protect the API but allow a new user to create an account when, obviously, they haven't/can't receive an access token.

Comment: The API should not be requiring a token for a registration call. Registration and Login calls are the entry point for the rest of the API and cannot possibly require a token.

Comment: @Dima thanks. So what is the best way to secure that function so it isn't abused?

Comment: That's a pretty open ended question. There are lots of things you can do but I guess it depends on what it is you're actually trying to secure. You can of course rate limit clients to perhaps try to prevent a brute force attack on accounts but aside from that, what sort of problems are you expecting?

Comment: I was just wondering what the best practices are. Rate limiting seems like a good idea. Not expecting any problems, just preparing for the worst :) If you want to put your first comment as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API should not be requiring a token for a registration call. Registration and Login calls are the entry point for the rest of the API and cannot possibly require a token.